# What is more performant way to use TypeScript with Webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack

In the Typescript documentation there is [an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html#create-a-webpack-configuration-file) that uses `ts-loader` plugin to digest TypeScript files like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
};
```

Other option is to use `tsc` (Typescript compiler) as part of `package.json script` like

```
"build": "tsc && webpack"
```

**Which is more performant way to work with TypeScript with Webpack?**

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use `ts-loader` as it's allow more fine-grained optimizations. You can cache intermediate results with [cache-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/cache-loader) or [hard-source-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin), run it in multiple threads with [happy-pack](https://github.com/amireh/happypacm). Webpack is also including some optimizations in it's [webpack 5 milestone](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6527)

PS. about `awesome-typescript-loader` - [github page](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader) covers all differences between it and `ts-loader` really well. It doesn't support `HappyPack` but on the other side have cache and better integration in babel. I recommend to try both options and choose whichever works faster, it's basically a few lines change in a config.